# Discord.py - 'id': target.id AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' - in version 1.7.3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am facing a problem.

I am using `discord.py-1.7.3` and this code to get and reply to messages in DM:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json

with open("config.json") as f:
  configData = json.load(f)

token = configData["TOKEN"]

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == message.author.dm_channel.id:
    msg = message.content
    msg_low = msg.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    if msg_low.startswith('name'):
      try:
        print(message.content)
        await message.author.send("Hello {username} {id}".format(username = message.author.name, id = message.author.id))
      except:
          print("problem")
```

Everything is working fine - until I send a message. As soon as I send it,

I get this error on the code

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

in this line

```
if message.channel.id == message.author.dm_channel.id:
```

and it also ignores the exception saying this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
```

How do I need to change the code, or what should I do?

Comment: Which line does that happen on? Is that a [mcve] already? What is the full backtrace of the exception? In any case, the error is pretty obvious and there are several similar questions concerning the error, read some of those.

Comment: The error occurs in this line. 
   `if message.channel.id == message.author.dm_channel.id:`

And I already read those, but sorry it didn't solve the problem. 

And this is the minimal code I could give for better understanding. 

And this is the traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)`


I hope it helps. @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: `message.channel` is `None`. You should ask yourself why that is the case, because all this depends on that. Also, please add the backtrace to the question, not to the comments. All relevant info should be there.

Answer (score 0):

create the dm channel using `Member.create_dm()` it returns a DMChannel object, so store it in a variable so that you can access its `id` attribute.
Don't worry it won't send a message in the DM nor will it create a new empty one if it already exists

you can call it only if `author.dm_channel` returns `None` using some basic if statements to avoid calling it each time

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  dmchannel = await message.author.create_dm()
  if message.channel.id == dmchannel.id:
    msg = message.content
    msg_low = msg.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    if msg_low.startswith('name'):
      try:
        print(message.content)
        await message.author.send("Hello {username} {id}".format(username = message.author.name, id = message.author.id))
      except:
          print("problem")
```

Comment: There is a DM channel actually.

Comment: I just did but now I am getting this new error whereas it is sending the message to the user. 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    dmchannel = await message.author.create_dm()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 764, in create_dm
    data = await state.http.start_private_message(self.id)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request 
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user`

Can you look into it? @AneeshYR

Comment: @JoyantaJ.Mondal maybe you've disabled DMs, or whoever it is testing the bot. If you share a server with the bot, Go to privacy settings when you right click on the server icon and check **Allow DMs from server members**. Maybe ask someone else to try too

Comment: DMs from server members is allowed too.